# PHP: How can I dynamically input the values in the tabs from an array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have a `PHP` array, in which I have some related info's to echo like this.

```
<?php 

    $options = array(

        array("name" => "Title",
            "desc" => "Description",
            "type" => '_one',
            "tab-name" => "Tab 1"

        ),

        array("name" => "Title2",
            "desc" => "Description2",
            "type" => '_two',
            "tab-name" => "Tab 2"

        ),

        array("name" => "Title3",
            "desc" => "Description3",
            "type" => '_three',
            "tab-name" => "Tab 3"

        )

    )

?>
```

I have made a function to echo out the name, desc and that is working perfectly

**Here it is:**

```
<?php

function create_heading($value) {
    echo '<h2>'.$value['name'].'</h2>';
}
function create_description($value){
    echo '<p>'.$value['desc'].'</p>'
}

function wrapper1($value) {
    echo '<h1>This is the wrapper 1</h1>'
    create_heading($value);
    create_description($value);
}

function wrapper2($value) {
    echo '<h1>This is the wrapper 2</h1>'
    create_heading($value);
    create_description($value);
}

function wrapper2($value) {
    echo '<h1>This is the wrapper 3</h1>'
    create_heading($value);
    create_description($value);
}


function render_things($options) {
    foreach ($options as $value) {
        switch($value['type']) {
            case "one":
                wrapper1($value);
                break;
            case "two":
                wrapper2($value);
            case "three":
                wrapper3($value);
        }
    }
}


render_things();

?>
```

**So what's the problem:**

The problem is how can I dynamically echo out these value inside the tab according to the tab-name in the array means I have given the value of the second array in tab-name is two so it should print in the second tab if I change it to one or three it should print the values to one or three respectively.

```css
body {font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;}

/* Style the tab */
div.tab {
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

/* Style the buttons inside the tab */
div.tab button {
    background-color: inherit;
    float: left;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    transition: 0.3s;
    font-size: 17px;
}

/* Change background color of buttons on hover */
div.tab button:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Create an active/current tablink class */
div.tab button.active {
    background-color: #ccc;
}

/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
    display: none;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-top: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'tab1')" id="defaultOpen">tab 1</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'tab2')">tab 2</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'tab3')">Tab 3</button>
</div>

<div id="tab1" class="tabcontent">
  <h1>This is tab 1</h1>
</div>

<div id="tab2" class="tabcontent">
  <h1>This is tab 2</h1>
</div>

<div id="tab3" class="tabcontent">
  <h1>This is tab 3</h1>
</div>

<script>
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}

// Get the element with id="defaultOpen" and click on it
document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
</script>
```

**NOTE:** I don't want to use js for implementing these info's so please guy avoid js answers if it is possible with PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your php page need to be like this:-

```
<style>
body {font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;}

/* Style the tab */
div.tab {
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

/* Style the buttons inside the tab */
div.tab button {
    background-color: inherit;
    float: left;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    transition: 0.3s;
    font-size: 17px;
}

/* Change background color of buttons on hover */
div.tab button:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Create an active/current tablink class */
div.tab button.active {
    background-color: #ccc;
}

.tabcontent {
    display: none;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-top: none;
}
</style>
<?php
  // i assume that your page have this array available
 $options = array(

        array("name" => "Title",
            "desc" => "Description",
            "type" => '_one',
            "tab-name" => "Tab 1"

        ),

        array("name" => "Title2",
            "desc" => "Description2",
            "type" => '_two',
            "tab-name" => "Tab 2"

        ),

        array("name" => "Title3",
            "desc" => "Description3",
            "type" => '_three',
            "tab-name" => "Tab 3"

        )

    );

?>
<div class="tab">
<?php foreach($options as $option){?>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick='openCity(event, "<?php echo str_replace(" ","",$option["tab-name"]);?>")' id="defaultOpen"><?php echo $option['tab-name'];?></button>
<?php } ?>
</div>


<?php foreach ($options as $opti){?>
    <div id="<?php echo str_replace(' ','',$opti['tab-name']);?>" class="tabcontent">
      <?php foreach($opti as $key=>$val){?>
      <h1><?php echo $key;?> : <?php echo $val;?></h1>
      <?php } ?>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
<script>
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}

// Get the element with id="defaultOpen" and click on it
document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
</script>
```

Output:- http://prntscr.com/fydwix  And http://prntscr.com/fydwnx And http://prntscr.com/fydwsg

Comment: changing the name of the page is required

Comment: No not at all. i am just saying that i have given a name `page.php` . you have to use your name

Comment: Checking and fixing some issues.

Comment: I have query and that is how can I let suppose I have one more value in array the fourth array with the different value but the tab-name is same as the 2nd tab ( that is Tab 2 ) so the problem is it is going to create a new tab with the name Tab 2 I want it to be in the same tab means want a query to check that the tab is already exist or not

Comment: @OwaizYusufi  it's your responsibility to manipulate the array first and make it in the current format (that means if you have two sub-array have same tab name then you have to do iteration and merger there values to one and make a unique array of each tab-name). BTW your current problem solve or not?

Comment: Thanks for the help:). Have a nice day.

Comment: @OwaizYusufi  you can ask a new question with your new requirement. Just post your array and add some identical sub-arrays and then ask what you want as a desired output. BTW glad to help you :):)